# SQL : Getting count of a column and then multiplying it with a column from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables in my database,

1. Students-has student id,
2. Instructors which has instructor id, course name and hourly pay.
3. Enrollment table which has student id, course name, instructor.

I need to write a query to get the max amount of money paid to an instructor. Somethings to consider

- A student can enroll into multiple courses
- An instructor can teach multiple courses (Instructor is paid the same for each course)
- Multiple instructors can teach the same course.

I came up with the required tables to get the entries first.

select  hourlyPay, ins_id, stu_id from Instructors, Enrollment where Enrollment.ins_id = Instructors.Instr_id group by hourlyPay,ins_ID,stu_id

This gives me the output:
[image]

My end goal is to multiply the hourly pay with the student count and get the maximum, Could somebody please help me do it? I want the student count per instructor multiplied with the hourly pay.

Comment: How do you know the number of hours paid for a course? Is the instructor paid per student or the same rate regardless of the number of students? Please show your tables structures and some sample data?

Comment: We just need the highest hourly rate. The instructor is paid the same per student. In the above image Instructor 205 would have to be returned because He is teaching 2 students and is paid 38$ so 2*38 = 76$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't know the data and complete requirement. You can try something below:

(This top 1 works in SQL Server). I think in Orcle you need try FETCH FIRST number ROWS ONLY;)

```
select top 1 ins_id,sum(hourlyPay) Pay
from(
    select hourlyPay
          , ins_id
          , stu_id 
    from Instructors
    Join Enrollment ON Enrollment.ins_id = Instructors.Instr_id 
    group by hourlyPay,ins_ID,stu_id
 ) a
 group by ins_id
 order by 2 desc
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Roshan, I modified it a little to get the required output :

select Max(sum(hourlyPay) ) Pay 
from (select hourlyPay,
 ins_id, 
stu_id
 from Instructors, Enrollment where Enrollment.ins_id = Instructors.Instr_id
 group by hourlyPay,ins_ID,stu_id
) a 
group by ins_id

Comment: @pursuitoflearning - Cool. But the joins which you are using are outdate. change the joins to ANSI which I gave in my example